# Haproxy: Is there a way of testing for two occurrences of a character in path without resorting to regex?

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to write an ACL rule for haproxy.  I want it to be true for paths that contain two or more forward slashes.   Ie:

```
/ -> false
/test -> false
/test/test -> true
```

Is there a way of doing this without resorting to regexes?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible. Regex is the perfect tool for this.
I'd recommend using an online regex tool, so you can test your regex accordingly before changing your ACL rule.

Try https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much.  I try to avoid regexes because of the possible performance implications, but looks like it'll have to do here.